# CanActive url added to history even when returning false

Tags: angular

CanActive adds skiped path to history.

I have the following guard

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.router.url === '/') {
        this.router.navigate(['/category']);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When the url is / it gets redirected to /category but the / path is added to history. This causes the user to navigate back to the / page.

Any idea why / is added to the history?

Answer (score 0):

Clear browser history before redirecting to "category":

```
this.location.replaceState('/'); // clears history
this.router.navigate(['/category']);
```

Comment: Hi @Set, I tried this.location.replaceState('/'); but it doesn't clear it.